# How to install .NET 4 on Windows XP without getting error 0x8024402F from Windows Update?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, .net-4.0

Installing .NET 4 on an updated Windows XP machine (sometimes?) results in breaking Windows Update. When .NET 4 is installed, Windows Update consistently fails with error code 0x8024402F. Removal of the .NET 4 installation returns Windows update to work.

Is it possible to have Windows Update working with .NET 4 installed on Windows XP?

UPDATE:It started working, and I have no idea why. Something on this page might be the solution but I can't be sure because I tried to reboot and update after every proposed solution and it want's working. If you have the same problem and find what fixes it please share.

Answer (score 0):

Googleing this error results in a connectivity issue found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941).  Not sure if this is what you're looking for but there is a fix it button downloaded provided by Microsoft worth checking out.

This is not something I've ever ran into honestly so it may be just a glitch or a bug from an improper install or corrupt file that is necessary to validate the install.

Comment: I've tried the FixIt from Microsoft, I have tried reinstalling .NET 4, and I've tried reinstalling Windows. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Install the update and reboot
go to services and disable windows update
delete C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution
turn "windows update" back on
Run windows update
```

Comment: Looks like a quote. What's your source?

Comment: @RhysGibson Years of experience.  I have fixed "Windows Update" this way dozens of times.  It is formatted like that because otherwise the wiki runs everything together in 1 line instead of appearing as step by step instructions.

Comment: @cybernard I have followed the instructions. Stopping the service allowed for the folder to be deleted, and running Windows or Microsoft update after that looked like running them for the first time and a new folder was created. Sadly, as long as .NET 4 is still installed, the error stays.

Comment: @SoleSoul Keep .NET installed and goto tweaking.com  and download "Tweaking.com - Windows Repair (All in One) v1.9.15 Released"  Run this utility.  Goto "Start Repairs and click "Start" and uncheck all the boxes except "Windows Update".  Then click "start".  "Wait patiently........."  You will probably have to reboot.

Comment: @cybernard Ok, the repair ran twice, once under the current user and once under SYSTEM, finished successfully, and the machine was rebooted. Running Windows Update after that looked like running it for the first time, just as it was when I deleted the folder.
Unfortunately, regarding the error, it is still here, exactly the same.

Comment: @SoleSoul  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/685f7bc3-7078-4e52-8097-3240066f803f/windows-update-client-failed-to-detect-with-error-0x8024402f  Try the 3rd answer.

Comment: @cybernard This solution did not change anything either. BTW, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had success solving this issue on an XP machine by ensuring that the regional and time settings where correct

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case here. Regional and time settings are correct and synchronize correctly with Microsoft servers. Thanks though.